# group comparisons - normality of the distribution

Tags: multiple-comparisons, normality-assumption, manova, nonparametric

When comparing 3 different groups on a certain variable and one of the groups does not have a normal distribution (as verified by the Shapiro test) whilst the other to do, would you think it is best to compare both groups with normal distributions using a parametric test and then conduct the other comparisons (between the groups with normal and not normal distribution) using the nonparametric tests or do you think it would be best to just use nonparametric testing for all comparisons?

To make this clear:
group A has a normal distribution
group B has a normal distribution
group c does not have a normal distribution

Do you think it would be best to use parametric testing when comparing the performance of group A and B and use nonparametric testing when comparing the performance of group A and C /B and C? Or should we just use non parametric testing for groups A, B and C all together?

Comment: What is the actual hypothesis you're interested in?

Comment: I am interested in verifying whether there performance differences between all three groups.